# Oracle XMLType - Loading from XML flat-file as chunks

Tags: oracle, xmltype

Using Java 8 and Oracle 11g. Regarding loading XML data from a flat file into an Oracle XMLType field. I can make it work with this code:

```
    private String readAllBytesJava7(String filePath)   {
    Files files;
    Paths paths;
    String content;

    content = "";
    try {
        content = new String ( Files.readAllBytes( Paths.get(filePath) ) );
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        log.error(e);
    }
    return content;
}


    pstmt = oracleConnection.prepareStatement("update MYTABLE set XML_SOURCE = ? where TRANSACTION_NO = ?");
    xmlFileAsString = this.readAllBytesJava7(fileTempLocation);
    xmlType = XMLType.createXML(oracleConnection, xmlFileAsString);
    pstmt.setObject(1,xmlType);
    pstmt.setInt(2, ataSpecHeader.id);
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

But as you might surmise, that only works for small XML files... Anything too large will cause a memory exception.

What I'd like to do is load the XML file in "chunks" as described here:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/a83724/oralob2.htm
and
https://community.oracle.com/thread/4721

Those posts show how to load a BLOB/CLOB column from a flat-file by "chunks". I can make it work if the column is blob/clob, but I couldn't adapt it for an XMLType column. Most of what I found online in regards to loading an XMLType column deals with using the oracle-directory object or using sql-loader, but I won't be able to use those as my solution. Is there any kind of post/example that someone knows of for how to load an XML file into an XMLType column as "chunks"?

Additional information:
I'm trying to take what I see in the posts for blob/clob and adapt it for XMLType. Here's the issues I'm facing:

```
sqlXml = oracleConnection.createSQLXML();
pstmt = oracleConnection.prepareStatement("update MYTABLE set 
XML_SOURCE = XMLType.createXML('<e/>') where 1=1 and TRANSACTION_NO = ?");
pstmt.setInt(1, ataSpecHeader.id);
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

With blob/clob, you start out by setting the blob/clob field to "empty" (so it isn't null)... I'm not sure how to do this with XMLType... the closest I can get it just to set it to some kind of xml as shown above.

The next step is to select the blob/clob field and get the output stream on it. Something like what is shown here:

```
cmd = "SELECT XML_SOURCE FROM MYTABLE WHERE TRANSACTION_NO = ${ataSpecHeader.id} FOR UPDATE ";
stmt = oracleConnection.createStatement();
rset = stmt.executeQuery(cmd);
rset.next();
xmlType = ((OracleResultSet)rset).getOPAQUE(1);
//clob = ((OracleResultSet)rset).getCLOB(1);
//blob = ((OracleResultSet)rset).getBLOB(1);
clob = xmlType.getClobVal();
//sqlXml = rset.getSQLXML(1);
//outstream = sqlXml.setBinaryStream();
//outstream = blob.getBinaryOutputStream();
outstream = clob.getAsciiOutputStream();
//At this point, read the XML file in "chunks" and write it to the outstream object by doing: outstream.write
```

The lines that are commented-out are to show the different things I've tried. To re-state... I can make it work fine if the field in the table is a BLOB or CLOB. But I'm not sure what to do if it's an XMLType. I'd like to get an outstream handle to the XMLType field so I can write to it, as I would if it were a BLOB or CLOB. Notice for BLOB/CLOB it selects the blob/clob field with "for update" and then gets an Outstream on it so I can write to it. For XMLType, i tried getting the field to an XMLType java class and SQLXML java class, but it won't work that way. I also tried getting the field first as xmltype/sqlxml and then casting to blob/clob to then get an outstream, but it won't work either. The truth is, I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do in order to be able to write to the XMLType field as a stream/chunks.

Comment: If you can make it work with a CLOB, can't you just change your update to `set XML_SOURCE = XMLType(?)`?

Comment: It would still leave me at the same problem.... If the clob-variable I'm updating with is too large, then it will cause memory exceptions. This happens even if the field is a clob field... Which is why the technique shown in those posts is necessary for putting a large clob value into the database... It must be done via a stream/chunks as opposed to a straight-forward update.

Comment: To add more to my original question... The two main points I'm struggling with as it relates to adapting the method shown in the two posts for XMLType are: 1) Initializing the XMLType to empty (as opposed to null)... For both blob/clob, there is an empty_blob() and empty_clob() method to initialize them to empty (as opposed to null) as a starting point to start writing to. I'm not sure how to do this for an XMLType.

Comment: The 2nd point is getting a reference to the XMLType that lets you then get an OutputStream you can use to write to it in "chunks". For both the blob and clob, you can do a "get Blob/Clob" and then do a "get Outputstream" on the blob/clob, by which you can then write to it. Not sure how to do this with an XMLtype

Comment: My first comment was meant to imply you then bind the `?` as a CLOB, using the mechanism you've already found. Oracle then converts that CLOB to XMLType. And going the other way you can use `<XMLType>.getClobVal()` and retrieve it as a streamed CLOB value?

Comment: I edited my original post to show more information as to what I'm trying to make it match the method I saw in the posts/blogs.... I believe that should clarify what I was trying.